# Problem involving set systems - combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

The question is as follows:

$A \subset \mathbb{P}(X)$
is
called
a
cross-cut
if
for
every
$B \subset X$
there
exists $A' \in A$
with
$B \subset A'$ or
$A' \subset B$. Prove
that
every
cross-cut
contains
a
cross-cut
of
size
at
most
$n \choose \lfloor{n/2}\rfloor$.

I expect the solution is very short once you have the right idea, but I cannot think how to start. I'm not sure how to best identify redundancy in such a construction.

Any ideas? It follows a chapter on Sperner's lemma, and other similar results.

Comment: This is Exercise 13.23 in László Lovász, _Combinatorial Problems and Exercises_ (second edition).

The textbook idea is to consider a minimal cross-cut and to modify it to obtain a Sperner family, by replacing each edge.  This does not increase the size of the set system, so the bound applies.

Comment: Asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2974799/question-on-cross-cuts-contained-in-cross-cuts/3107129#3107129